# How to switch between jquery themes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, themes

We are using the redmond theme from jQuery UI and we have almost ready another theme completely customized for our customer.

I would like to let the userto choose its theme between the two.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to go about this is to use [the themeswitcher widget](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/ThemeSwitcher), or a modification of it.

You can see the source here: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/themeswitchertool/  Just change the theme URLs/images (if you want images) to the ones you have created.